# How to force page file expansion when using boost::file_mapping

Tags: c++, windows, performance, c++11, boost

in my current genetical algorithm I'm iterating over a couple of rather large files. Right now I'm using `boost::file_mapping` to access this data.

I have 3 different testcases I can launch the program on: (my computer has 8GB RAM, Windows 8.1, my different attempts at page file limits, read below)

1. 1000 files, about 4MB in size, so 4 GB total.
   This case is, when executed first a bit sluggish, but from the second iteration onwards, the memoryaccess isn't bottlenecking it anymore, and the speed is entirely limited by my CPU.
2. 1000 files, about 6MB in size, so 6 GB total.
   This is an entirely different scenario... The first iteration is proportionally slow, but even following iterations do not speed up. I have actually considered trying to load 4 GB to my memory and keep 2 GB mapped... Not sure this would actually work, but it may be worth a test... But even if this would work, this would not help with case c)...
3. 1000 files, about 13 MB in size, so 13 GB total.
   This is entirely hopeless. The first iteration is incredibly slow (which is understandable considering the amount of data), but even further iterations show no sign of speed improvement. And even a partial load to memory won't help much here.

Now I tried various settings for the page file limits:

1. managed by Win - the size of the pagefil stops at around 5-5.2 GB... never gets bigger. This obviously does not help with cases b) and c) and actually causes the files to cycle through... (it would actually be helpful, if at least the first 4 GB would stay, as it is right now, basically nothing is reused from the pagefile)
2. manual: min 1 GB, max 32 GB: the page file does not grow above 4.5GB
3. manual: min 16GB, max 32 GB: In case you haven't tried this yourself... don't do it. It makes booting almost impossible, and nothing runs smooth anymore... Yeah, I didn't test my program with this, as this was unacceptable.

So, what I'm looking for is some way to tell my Windows, that, when using page file settings 1) or 2), that i really really want to use a very large page file in this case for my program. But I don't want my Computer to entirely be run on the page file (as it basically happens with 3)) Is there any way I could force this?

Or is there any other way how to properly load the data in a way, so that at least from the second iteration onwards the access is done quick? The data consist only out of huge numbers of 64bit integers that are bitchecked against by my algorithm(there are a bunch of formating symbols in between every 200-300 ints), so I only need read access.

In case the info is needed, I'm using VS Pro 2013. Portability of the code isn't an issue, it only has to run on my notebook. And of course it is a 64bit application, and my processor supports that ;)

Comment: This does not make sense. When you memory-map a file, the memory is backed by *that* file. It doesn't occupy page file space. If you try to map more data into memory than you have physical RAM, then thrashing will occur as old pages get evicted from RAM to make room for whatever you're currently accessing. Page file size won't change this, only installing more RAM will (or trying to map less data simultaneously).

Comment: so then how can the behavior(increased speed from second iteration onwards) of a) be explained? Does it actually store all the files in my RAM (without the taskmanager showing it), while it can't do that in cases b) and c)?

Comment: When the data fits in RAM, it can all stay in the page *cache* (i.e. in RAM, *not* the page file). That explains the speedup after the first iteration.